# Как сделать filter к SimpleAdapter в ListFragment?

Tags: android, adapter

как правильно составить  фильтр чтоб находить нужные пункты списка с listView?

в моем коде вылетает на строчке sAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

```
public class FirstFragment extends ListFragment {

 final String ATTRIBUTE_NAME_TEXT = "text";
 final String ATTRIBUTE_NAME_LL = "ll";
 ListView lvSimple;
 SimpleAdapter sAdapter;
 EditText editsearch;
 Map<String, Object> m;
 ArrayList<Map<String, Object>> aData ;
 ArrayList<Map<String, Object>> mAllData;
 String product[] = new String[]{"one", "two", "three", "four", "five"};
 Integer degree[] = {99, 98, 97,96,96};

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_first, container, false);
    editsearch = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.inputSearch);
    return rootView;

} //End OnCreate()

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    aData = new ArrayList<Map<String, Object>>(product.length);
    mAllData= new ArrayList<>();

    for (int i = 0; i < product.length; i++) {
        m = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        m.put(ATTRIBUTE_NAME_TEXT, product[i]);

        m.put(ATTRIBUTE_NAME_LL, degree[i]);
        aData.add(m);
        //&
        mAllData.add(m); // for filter 
    }

    String[] from = {ATTRIBUTE_NAME_TEXT, ATTRIBUTE_NAME_LL};
    int[] to = {R.id.tvLoad, R.id.llLoad};

    SimpleAdapter sAdapter = new SimpleAdapter(getActivity(), aData, R.layout.e_list_item,
            from, to);
    setListAdapter(sAdapter);

    lvSimple = (ListView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.list_one);
    lvSimple.setAdapter(sAdapter);

    editsearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            String text = editsearch.getText().toString().toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault());

        }
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1,
                                      int arg2, int arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }
        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
                                  int arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            String text = editsearch.getText().toString().toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault());
            filter(text);
        }
    });

} //End onActivityCreated()

public void filter(String charText) {
    charText = charText.toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault());
    aData.clear();
    if (charText.length() == 0) {

        aData.addAll(mAllData);
    } else {
        for (Map<String, Object> wp : mAllData) {

            if (wp.keySet().contains(charText)) {
                aData .add((Map<String, Object>) wp);
            }
        }
    }
    sAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); // вылетает на этой строчке
}

}
```

stack trace:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.fts.sejo.foodadditive.FirstFragment.filter(FirstFragment.java:122)
at com.fts.sejo.foodadditive.FirstFragment$1.onTextChanged(FirstFragment.java:102)
at android.widget.TextView.sendOnTextChanged(TextView.java:7079)
at android.widget.TextView.handleTextChanged(TextView.java:7138)
at android.widget.TextView$ChangeWatcher.onTextChanged(TextView.java:8732)
at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.sendTextChanged(SpannableStringBuilder.java:962)
at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.replace(SpannableStringBuilder.java:496)
at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.replace(SpannableStringBuilder.java:435)
at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.replace(SpannableStringBuilder.java:30)
at android.text.method.QwertyKeyListener.onKeyDown(QwertyKeyListener.java:222)
at android.text.method.TextKeyListener.onKeyDown(TextKeyListener.java:136)
at android.widget.TextView.doKeyDown(TextView.java:5240)
at android.widget.TextView.onKeyDown(TextView.java:5059)
at android.view.KeyEvent.dispatch(KeyEvent.java:2609)
at android.view.View.dispatchKeyEvent(View.java:7086)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1358)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1358)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1358)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1358)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1358)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1358)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1358)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1358)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1358)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1358)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchKeyEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1892)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchKeyEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1369)
at android.app.Activity.dispatchKeyEvent(Activity.java:2356)
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.dispatchKeyEvent(AppCompatActivity.java:531)
at android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.dispatchKeyEvent(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:50)
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplBase$AppCompatWindowCallbackBase.dispatchKeyEvent(AppCompatDelegateImplBase.java:241)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchKeyEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1819)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverKeyEventPostIme(ViewRootImpl.java:3575)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.handleImeFinishedEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:3545)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewRootHandler.handleMessage(ViewRootImpl.java:2795)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: По какой причине вылетает  нужно самим догадаться или вы все же стектрейс приложите к вопросу.

Comment: мне кажется что у меня неправильная логика в filter()

Comment: `SimpleAdapter` реализует интерфейс `Filterable`. Лучше используйте его [для фильтрации списка](http://codetheory.in/android-filters/) и POJO-модели вместо `Map`